# Conflicts during scripted updates with Elasticsearch and .NET

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm collecting some statistics in Elasticsearch for the number of requests per hour to an API. Rather than indexing a new document per request, I'm updating a statistic document per user. On each request, I'm doing something like this from .NET:

```cs
client
    .Update<StatisticsDocument>(statsId, u => u
        .RetryOnConflict(3)
        .Script(s => s.Source("ctx._source.requests+=1"))
        .Upsert(new StatisticsDocument { Id = statsId, Requests = 1, User = userId, Created = thisHour }));
```

So, `requests` is incremented. If a document for this error and the user with `userId` doesn't exist, I'm creating a new one using the `Upsert`-method.

There can be more threads and processes calling this code, why I've added `RetryOnConflict(3)` to retry on conflict.

I'm seeing a pretty large number of conflicts anyway, especially under high load. I understand that retrying 3 times doesn't always solve this issue since there are many threads trying to update the same document over and over again. But I'm still surprised by a pretty high number of conflicts.

Any ideas about what to do here? I'm thinking about keeping the metric in memory and then writing it every minute or something like that. But if Elasticsearch and/or Nest has some kind of built-in feature to help even further, that would be the first priority to implement.

Comment: Would Transform APIs (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/put-transform.html) or Rollup APIs (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/rollup-put-job.html) work to transform data from an write-once immutable (_raw_) index, into more entity-centric documents (which is what these look like)? The _raw_ index could be a daily/weekly/monthly index that is deleted when finished with.

Comment: I definitely considered that. The main issue here is that I don't really want a document per request. I just want the counter per hour. Martijn suggested what I was thinking about here: https://twitter.com/Mpdreamz/status/1222169295695704066. To do something in memory and write it every second or so. Think I'll go with something like that. Just wanted to make sure that I didn't miss another obvious solution  Thanks Russ, your input is appreciated as always.